# Maximum number of concurrent writes to Cloudant

Tags: python-3.x, performance, couchdb, cloudant

I got a requirement some time back to see if we can improve the number of concurrent writes/sec to cloudant db. It was suggested by IBM to bump up the concurrency in Cloudant from default to 50 or 100 and see if it does anything for performance. Here is the link to IBM documentation that talks about these [settings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTPQH_1.0.0/com.ibm.cloudant.local.install.doc/topics/clinstall_ioq_guide.html)

So I wrote a script in python which creates a document in Cloudant and ran it against two of our dev Cloudant clusters for different number of threads. Here are the results :

DEV

```
Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 4
Total Time : 3.47 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 49 records/sec
Concurrency : Default

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 20
Total Time : 3.53
Number of writes/sec : ~ 47 records/sec
Concurrency : Default

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 20
Total Time : 3.38
Number of writes/sec : ~ 49 records/sec
Concurrency : 50

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 20
Total Time : 3.38
Number of writes/sec : ~ 49 records/sec
Concurrency : 100
```

DEV2

```
Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 4
Total Time : 2.82 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 59 records/sec
Concurrency : 50

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 4
Total Time : 3.32 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 50 records/sec
Concurrency : 50
IOQ Bypass : interactive

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 4
Total Time : 2.82 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 59 records/sec
Concurrency : 50
IOQ Bypass : None

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 4
Total Time : 2.88 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 58 records/sec
Concurrency : 50
IOQ Bypass : db_update

Number of records : 10000
Number of client threads : 20
Total Time : 2.89 mins
Number of writes/sec : ~ 58 records/sec
Concurrency : 50
IOQ Bypass : db_update
```

As can be seen, both clusters seem to have a threshold limit in terms of how many records it can write per sec, irrespective of number of client threads, Concurrency or IOQ bypass. For Dev1, it  never seem to get past 50 writes/sec and for Dev2 its 59 writes/sec. Now these are the clusters that are not even being used that much, hence I only expect to see a drop in that number further if we ran it against busier cluster.(like stg, prod)

So the question is, is there any other setting that we can possibly look at to get better performance ?

Thanks- Akshay

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the IOQ adjustments, but I would say that the easiest way to achieve a higher document write throughput is to use the [bulk API](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/api/document.html#bulk-operations). The `POST /db/_bulk_docs` endpoint should allow you to upload tens, hundreds or thousands of documents at once in a single API call. This will be much more efficient than individual piecemeal writes.

You can then ramp up the concurrency of how many bulk write requests you run at once to increase throughput.